# Why are English language essays written in past tenses?

Tags: writing-style, past-tense

As we are studying English from the nursery the thing that always confuses me is that whenever we write an essay it should be in past tenses and I always find difficulty in writing essays that way. I searched it many times. I take help from goggle, read grammar books  and consult my language professors. They just give me the reason that it is the custom to write in past tenses. I found so much difficulty but  no guide.  I post my question in this site so I may get the best guide and can write essays without any tenses mistakes

Comment: Essays aren't all written in the past tense. It really just depends on what you're writing about.

Comment: I've used the present tense for almost all of the essays I've written.